# VSCode - RestClient how can we reassign @ File Variables?

Tags: http, vscode-extensions, vscode-restclient

I'm testing a simple JWT authentication flow using RestClient and am using `@variable` file variables during the flow to store tokens from the respones. Specifically, I am trying to understand if and how the `@access_token` variable can be reassigned upon refreshing the token.

#### **Context:**

1. **Login Endpoint**: User logs in, and the server responds with an access token and a refresh token, which are stored in `@access_token` and `@refresh_token`, respectively.
2. **Access Token Expiry**: The access token is set to expire in 20s (for testing purposes).
3. **Refresh Token**: The `/token` endpoint is required to be hit with the `{{refresh_token}}` to get a new access token when the initial token expires.

#### **Workflow Example:**

```http
@baseUrl1 = http://localhost:3000
@baseUrl2 = http://localhost:4000
@access_token = {{login.response.body.accessToken}}
@refresh_token = "{{login.response.body.refreshToken}}"

### LOGIN
# @name login
POST {{baseUrl2}}/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "username": "Jim"
}

### GET POSTS USING ACCESS TOKEN
GET {{baseUrl1}}/posts HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}

### REFRESH ACCESS TOKEN
# @name get_refreshed_token
POST {{baseUrl2}}/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "token": {{refresh_token}}
}

### [QUERY] REASSIGN ACCESS TOKEN?
# @access_token = {{get_refreshed_token.response.body.accessToken}}

### LOGOUT
DELETE {{baseUrl2}}/logout HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "token": {{refresh_token}}
}
```

**What I Tried:**

I attempted to reassign the `@access_token` directly after obtaining a new access token when the original token expires, using the following line in my code:

```http
# @access_token = {{get_refreshed_token.response.body.accessToken}}
```

**Expectations:**

I expected that when I uncommented and utilized the line above, `@access_token` would update with the new token received from the `/token` endpoint, allowing the new token to be used in future API requests without issue.

**Actual Outcome:**

Unexpectedly, RestClient seems to retain only the last assignment of the `@access_token`. Thus, when I try to access an endpoint requiring the new token (like `/posts`), it fails and throws an error due to using the old, expired token.

**Additional Context:**

- If the requests are occurring for the first time and the `/token` endpoint hasn't been hit (meaning `get_refreshed_token` is empty), then `@access_token` becomes undefined because there is no value to assign.
- If I hit `/login` after `/token`, the `/login` does not overwrite `@access_token` with the line `@refresh_token = "{{login.response.body.refreshToken}}"` placed at the top of the code. RestClient seems to consistently prioritize the last `@access_token`.

**Additional Notes:**

I've reviewed RestClient documentation and forums looking for information on variable reassignment but haven't found asolution

#### **My point of question:**

In the "[QUERY] REASSIGN ACCESS TOKEN?" section of the code, you'll notice a commented line where I'm was testing to see what would happen if I the reassignment of `@access_token`. But when this line is uncommented, and I hit the `/login` endpoint, followed by `/posts` (with the access_token), it throws an error due to the wrong access token, that second @access_token is either empty or an old value from using `/token` to assign a access_token to `@access_token`.

#### **Questions:**

- Is it possible to reassign the `@access_token` in RestClient after it has been initially set?
- If possible, what is the correct way to achieve this without hindering subsequent API calls?
- If not, is there an alternative approach to managing refreshed access tokens within RestClient?